# Retrofit and Generics and Inconsistent API data

Tags: android, generics, retrofit

From Retrofit's documentation:

```
RESPONSE OBJECT TYPE

HTTP responses are automatically converted to a specified type using the RestAdapter's converter which defaults to JSON. The desired type is declared as the method return type or using the Callback or Observable.

@GET("/users/list")
List<User> userList();
```

Retrofit will automatically convert a returned response (JSON, XML, etc) into the desired object that is specified by the method.

In the documentation's case, it will return a List of User objects.

How can one interface retrofit with a badly designed API that returns a list of different typed objects.

The psudocode will look something like:

```
@GET("/users/list")
List<User|Pet> userList();
```

**Edit**: The API returns a mix of the two types together. There are no flags or switches to change that.

Example `/users/list`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "animal": "dog",
       "speak": "woof"
    },
    {
       "username": "Bob",
       "age": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When does it return "pet" and when does it return "user"? What is the condition for the change?

Comment: Edited the question in response. 

The API returns a mix of the two in a single array with the key "data"

Comment: I think you'll need to go plumbing with JSONObject, because the best you can get out of it is `List<Object>`.

Comment: You can register a  `TypeAdapter` to you `Gson` instance (set as a retrofit converter via `GsonConverter`) to transform into whatever type you want to determine based on the response at runtime.

Comment: I don't know if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427212/java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-datalist/31434735#31434735